# How do I limit number of elements in updated array using $push and $slice in MongoEngine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have a document with an array of subdocuments.

These are what the document and the subdocument look like:

```
class Activity_Comment(EmbeddedDocument):
    author_name = StringField()
    text_excerpt = StringField()
    url = StringField()


class Author_Activity(Document):
    author_id = StringField(required=True,primary_key=True)
    author_name = StringField()
    author_bio = StringField()
    latest_comments = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Activity_Comment))
```

There could be multiple server processes that could modify the the document at the same time.
So I want to use `update_one` method with `upsert=True`.

I also want to restrict the number of subdocuments in the array to 5.
It seems this is possible in MongoDB according to these links:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/limit-number-of-elements-in-updated-array/
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/

These links suggest that I should use `$push` to insert the subdocuments into the array and `$slice` to limit the array length to the desired value.

However, I haven't been able to figure out how to do this using MongoEngine. I tried the following code

```
Author_Activity.objects(author_id="1").update_one(push__latest_comments=activity_comment,slice__latest_comments=5, upsert=True)
```

but it threw the following exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/newsoftheworld/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py",
>   line 467, in update_one
>       upsert=upsert, multi=False, write_concern=write_concern, **update)   File
>   "/newsoftheworld/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py",
>   line 430, in update
>       update = transform.update(queryset._document, **update)   File "/newsoftheworld/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/transform.py",
>   line 181, in update
>       raise InvalidQueryError(e) InvalidQueryError: Cannot resolve field "slice"

Answer (score 0):

What about findAndModify with returted new value?
If you reached the limit - remove one.